# Obtener tecla presionada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el script que dejo a continuación pero me lanza un error al ejecutarlo en la línea 61:

```
from record import record
import os

class cliente(record):
  nombre = ""
  codigo = 0
  ultimapelicula = None
  habilitado = True

class pelicula(record):
  nombre = ""
  codigo = 0
  ultimocliente = 0
  habilitada = True

def abrirbasedatos():
  listaclientes = []
  listapeliculas = []

  ficheroclientes = abrirfichero ("Clientes.txt")
  if ficheroclientes != None:
    poblarlista(listaclientes, ficheroclientes,1)
    ficheroclientes.close()

  ficheropeliculas = abrirfichero ("Peliculas.txt")
  if ficheropeliculas != None:
    poblarlista(listapeliculas, ficheropeliculas,2)
    ficheropeliculas.close()
  return listaclientes, listapeliculas

def abrirfichero (nombrearchivo):
  try:
    return open (nombrearchivo, "r")
  except:
    print ("\n\n No se pu do abrir el fichero", nombrearchivo)
    return

def poblarlista(lista, fichero, numerolista):
    for linea in fichero:
        registro = linea.rstrip().split(",")
        if numerolista == 1:
            lista.append(cliente(nombre = registro[0], codigo = int(registro [1]), ultimapelicula = int(registro[2]), habilitado = convertirVF(registro[3])))
        elif numerolista == 2:
            lista.append(pelicula(nombre=registro [0], codigo = int(registro [1]), ultimocliente = int (registro [2]), habilitada = convertirVF(registro [3])))
    return
def convertirVF (cadena):
  if cadena == "True":
    return True
  elif cadena == "False":
    return False

def interconectarregistros():
  global listaclientes
  for c in range(len(listaclientes)):
    listaclientes[c].ultimapelicula=buscarregistro(listaclientes[c].ultimapelicula,2)
    return

def mostrarinicio():
  os.system("cls")
  print ("\n\n\n *//VIDEO CLUB// *\n")
  print ("Presione una tecla...\n\n")
  keypressed(2)
  return

def mostrarmenu(opciones,ls):
  os.system("cls")
  print (" *//VIDEO CLUB// *\n")
  print (opciones)
  return elegiropcion(ls)

def elegriopcion (limitesuperior):
  opcion = keypressed(2)
  while not opcionesvalida (opcion, limitesuperior):
    opcion = keypressed(2)
  return opcion

def opcionesvalida(opcion,ls):
  if opcion == "Escape":
    return True
  for elemento in range (1,ls + 1):
    if opcion == str(elemento):
      return True
  return False
#constantes
opcionesmenuppal = "- Menú Principal - \n\n1) Gestion de VideoClub\n2) Gestion de Peliculas\n3) Gestion de Clientes\n"
opcionesmenuclub = "- Menú VIdeoClub - \n\n1) Alquilar Pelicula\n2) Devolver Pelicula\n"
opcionesmenupelicula ="- Menú Peliculas - \n\n1) Consultar Pelicula\n2) Agregar Pelicula\n3) Eliminar Pelicula\n"
opcionesmenuclientes = "- Menú Cliente - \n\n1) Consultar Cliente\n2) Agregar Cliente\n3) Borrar Cliente\n"


# perte principal del programa
listaclientes, listapeliculas = abrirbasedatos()

mostrarinicio()

while True:
  opcionprincipal = mostarmenu (opcionesmenuppal, 3)
  if opcionprincipal == "1":
    mostarmenu(opcionesmenuclub,2)
  elif opcionprincipal == "2":
    mostrarmenu(opcionesmenupelicula,3)
  elif opcionprincipal == "3":
    mostrarmenu(opcionesmenuclientes,3)

  if opcionprincipal == "Escape":
    mostrarinicio()
```

Este es el error que me lanza:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "club.py", line 93, in <module>
>     mostrarinicio()
>   File "club.py", line 61, in mostrarinicio
>     keypressed(2)
> NameError: name 'keypressed' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Hola Marco. No tienes definida esa función o método keypressed. Aparentemente se espera que actúe como un "keyboard Listener" que retorna la tecla pulsada. Hay varios módulos que permiten esto (algunos solo para un sistema operativo, otros multisistema como [pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput)). si te has basado en algún código de terceros sería de gran ayuda que agregaras la fuente.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu paciencia, pero es que el código que coloque es como esta en el video que estoy viendo, creo que en vez de aprender me estoy enredando mas. porque al que publica el video le corre siempre sin error y a mi no.

Comment: Pero el método o función `keypressed` debe venir de algún lado y estar definida en algún momento, incluido en el caso del vídeo. Te debe faltar algún `import` o el método definido en este mismo script. Si no es así, el del vídeo omite algo...

Comment: Bueno, voy a bandonar este curso y a buscar otro, porque la persona que lo publica no responde comentarios ni consulta a sus alumnos, gracias por tu apoyo. deberías de grabar cursos tui. Se nota que tienes conocimientos.

Comment: Marco de nada, estamos todos por aquí para aprender, preguntando y respondiendo. Creo que he encontrado un poco por casualidad la causa de tu problema. aunque dejes el curso dejo una respuesta por si te interesa la causa del problema y posibles soluciones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que en el curso se usa como entorno de programación [PythonG](https://www3.uji.es/~dllorens/PythonG/).

`keypressed` es una funcionalidad del IDE (PythonG) que permite capturar las teclas pulsadas,  por lo que no te va a servir de nada si usas otro IDE para programar o ejecutas en la terminal tu script.

Los ejemplos del curso están basados o expuestos en el libro [Introducción a la programación con Python](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiD5PCPhrPWAhXLhrQKHeWHBPoQFgg3MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.u-cursos.cl%2Fingenieria%2F2011%2F2%2FCC3501%2F1%2Fmaterial_docente%2Fbajar%3Fid_material%3D381752&usg=AFQjCNEh7Q-2t3oApsFhtsV_zNxlgP-FMQ) (Andres Marzal e Isabel Gracia, Universitat Jaume I ), donde si se explica el uso de este IDE al principio del capitulo 3 y habla de `keypressed` en el apartado B.3. También tienen el código que muestras explicado en el ejemplo "Gestion de un videoclub" en el capitulo 7.3.4.

Dado que es una forma no portable de capturar teclas pulsadas, es mejor prescindir de estos métodos. Una opción común es usar un `input` y un menú.

No obstante, podemos emular el mismo comportamiento que tiene `keypressed` sin salirse de la biblioteca estándar de Python. Podemos capturar pulsaciones de teclas usando `msvcrt` en windows y `termios` en Linux:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':

    import msvcrt

    def keypressed():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        if key == b"\x1b": #ESC
            return "Escape"
        else:
            return key.decode("ANSI")

elif sys.platform == 'linux':

    import os
    import termios
    TERMIOS = termios

    def keypressed():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        new[3] = new[3] & ~TERMIOS.ICANON & ~TERMIOS.ECHO
        new[6][TERMIOS.VMIN] = 1
        new[6][TERMIOS.VTIME] = 0
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, TERMIOS.TCSANOW, new)
        key = None
        try:
            key = os.read(fd, 4)
            if key == b'\x1b':
                key = "Escape"
            else:
                key = key.decode()

        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, TERMIOS.TCSAFLUSH, old)
        return key
```

La función se llama igual que en tu caso pero sin argumentos:

```
opcion = keypressed()
```

> **Nota**: el script ha de ejecutarse ne la terminal/CMD para su correcto funcionamiento. No hay garantía de que funcione en la shell propia de un IDE determinado.

Hay muchas mas opciones fuera de la stdlib, como [pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput), [pyHook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook), [keyboard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/), etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo. y si en verdad me interesa saber el porque del error eso me ayuda a aprender mas.

Comment: @MarcoSalazar pues el error era simplemente eso, que es una funcionalidad propia y exclusiva de PythonG, el programa que se usa en este manual para programar y ejecutar el código. Por cierto, esta misma gente tiene una versión mucho mas completa pero para Python 3 de este libro. Es de libre uso para fines no comerciales y didácticos, puedes descargarlo de [aqui](http://repositori.uji.es/xmlui/bitstream/10234/102653/1/s93.pdf) si te interesa. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias toda ayuda es bienvenida. Estoy devorando todo de Python, en verdad quiero apenderlo. Programo muy bien en VBA con excel, pero quiero hacer programas independientes sin tener que depender del office.