# ¿Cómo realizar un 'Presione una tecla para continuar...' en Python 3.X?

Tags: python, windows

### Hola a Todos!

Me preguntaba como puedo reemplazar el siguiente comando:

```
import os
os.system("Pause")
```

Muchas personas me dijeron que lo reemplace por:

```
input("Presione una tecla para continuar...")
```

Pero, al utilizar este último método, me dí cuenta que el Usuario puede escribir libremente, como podemos apreciar en la siguiente imagen:
[image: Imagen de ejemplo!]
La verdad es que me parece que eso queda poco profesional. ¿Alguna solución?

**Muchas Gracias**

Comment: Mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103608/15089. `msvcrt.getch` puede valerte en tu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` solo retornará (y por tanto permitirá que continúe la ejecución, ya que es bloqueante) cuando <kbd>Enter</kbd> sea pulsada. Mientras tanto te permite introducir el texto que quieras, cómo es lógico ya que para eso está pensada.

Necesitas por tanto una función bloqueante y que retorne en cuanto sea pulsada cualquier tecla. En Windows lo más aproximado es usar [`msvcrt.getch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) de la biblioteca estándar para ello:

```
import msvcrt

print("Presione una tecla para continuar...")
msvcrt.getch()
```

Si buscas que se continúe cuando una determinada tecla sea pulsada basta con usar `while`:

```
import msvcrt

print("Presione 'Esc' para continuar...")
key = None
while key != '\x1b':
    key = msvcrt.getch()
```

Podemos usar `msvcrt.getwch()` que es igual a `getch` pero que retorna el valor Unicode.

```
import msvcrt

print("Presione 'ñ' para continuar...")
key = None
while key != 'ñ':
    key = msvcrt.getwch()
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu aporte!